# wp_enqueue JavaScript in child-theme (ReferenceError) using Search & Go

Tags: functions, javascript, child-theme

This is my first post here, so I hope I pasted the code well and you'll stand by interpreting the problem.

I have deregistered and dequeued two scripts in my childtheme. When removing and adding only the first script (listing.js) all works fine, no problem. But when I also remove and add more script the page becomes dysfunctional and I get reference errors.

[Here's a screenshot of what my debug plugin gives me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASQva.png)

Here's the relevant part of my functions.php in childtheme:

```js
    function remove_script() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'search_and_go_elated_listings' );
    wp_dequeue_script(  'search_and_go_elated_listings' );

    wp_deregister_script( 'search_and_go_elated_third_party' );
    wp_dequeue_script(  'search_and_go_elated_third_party' );

    wp_deregister_script( 'search_and_go_elated_modules' );
    wp_dequeue_script(  'search_and_go_elated_modules' );

    wp_deregister_script( 'search_and_go_elated_blog' );
    wp_dequeue_script(  'search_and_go_elated_blog' );

    wp_deregister_script( 'eltd-like' );
    wp_dequeue_script(  'eltd-like' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'remove_script', 20 );

function add_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bijles_search_and_go_elated_listings', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/listings.js', array('jquery', 'underscore', 'jquery-ui-autocomplete'), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bijles_search_and_go_elated_third_party', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/third-party.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true  );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bijles_search_and_go_elated_modules', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/modules.js', array('jquery'), false, true  );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bijles_search_and_go_elated_blog', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/blog.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true  );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bijles_eltd-like', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/like.min.js', array(), false, true  );
};
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script', 100);
```

Similar but unanswered question can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103884/javascript-not-defined-but-included):

Hope you all can help me out. I've been learning but can't figure this out myself!

ADDED (29-6-2016):

This is what I found searching for "search_and_go_elated_listings" in parent theme. functions.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'search_and_go_elated_listing_assets' ) ) {

    function search_and_go_elated_listing_assets() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'search_and_go_elated_listings', ELATED_ASSETS_ROOT.'/css/listings.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'search_and_go_elated_listings', ELATED_ASSETS_ROOT.'/js/listings.min.js', array('jquery', 'underscore', 'jquery-ui-autocomplete'), false, true );

        if(search_and_go_elated_is_responsive_on()) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'search_and_go_elated_listings_responsive', ELATED_ASSETS_ROOT.'/css/listings-responsive.min.css' );
        }

    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'search_and_go_elated_listing_assets' );

}
```

This is what I found searching for "search_and_go_elated_modules" in parent theme:

```
wp_enqueue_script('search_and_go_elated_modules', ELATED_ASSETS_ROOT.'/js/modules.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
```

Besides wp_enqueue_script, I also found a couple of instances of wp_localize_script for this handle.

Hope this helps!

ADDED (30-6-2016):

In parent wp_localize_script is used 6 times in framework belonging to the theme, which I will not post for now. It is used twice in functions.php, were we also see "eltdGlobalVars", which is mentioned in one of the errors. Please see below:

```
if(!function_exists('search_and_go_elated_get_global_variables')) {
    /**
     * Function that generates global variables and put them in array so they could be used in the theme
     */
    function search_and_go_elated_get_global_variables() {

        $global_variables = array();
        $element_appear_amount = -150;

        $global_variables['eltdAddForAdminBar'] = is_admin_bar_showing() ? 32 : 0;
        $global_variables['eltdElementAppearAmount'] = search_and_go_elated_options()->getOptionValue('element_appear_amount') !== '' ? search_and_go_elated_options()->getOptionValue('element_appear_amount') : $element_appear_amount;
        $global_variables['eltdFinishedMessage'] = esc_html__('No more posts', 'search-and-go');
        $global_variables['eltdMessage'] = esc_html__('Loading new posts...', 'search-and-go');

        $global_variables = apply_filters('search_and_go_elated_js_global_variables', $global_variables);

        wp_localize_script('search_and_go_elated_modules', 'eltdGlobalVars', array(
            'vars' => $global_variables
        ));

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'search_and_go_elated_get_global_variables');
}

if(!function_exists('search_and_go_elated_per_page_js_variables')) {
    /**
     * Outputs global JS variable that holds page settings
     */
    function search_and_go_elated_per_page_js_variables() {
        $per_page_js_vars = apply_filters('search_and_go_elated_per_page_js_vars', array());

        wp_localize_script('search_and_go_elated_modules', 'eltdPerPageVars', array(
            'vars' => $per_page_js_vars
        ));
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'search_and_go_elated_per_page_js_variables');
}
```

ADDED (1-7-2016):

Several searches for the definition of eltd.modules.listings on line 4 but found nothing. First 10 lines of listings.js:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    var listings = {};
    eltd.modules.listings = listings;

    listings.eltdOnDocumentReady = eltdOnDocumentReady;
    listings.eltdOnWindowLoad = eltdOnWindowLoad;
    listings.eltdOnWindowResize = eltdOnWindowResize;
```

Comment: This probably has something to do with the hooks. You use the 'wp_print_scripts' to remove the scripts and 'wp_enqueue_scripts' to add them. It would help significantly if you post the code part of the parent theme where the 'search_and_go_elated_listings' and 'search_and_go_elated_modules' are enqueued.

Comment: I just added some lines in post.

Comment: This makes things a bit simpler and complex at the same time. You see the conditional there:

`if ( ! function_exists( 'search_and_go_elated_listing_assets' ) ) { ... }`

This is a pluggable function. Which means that you don't have to deregister and deque the 'search_and_go_elated_listings'. Instead, create the function with the same name (search_and_go_elated_listing_assets) in your child theme, and enqueue your own scripts.

Comment: The tricky part would be the wp_localize_script. It is usually used in two cases: to make some strings in the script translatable or to pass some data to the script. Really hard to tell what is your case. But this is probably the cause of the problem.

Comment: I also expect the problems lies with the latter (search_and_go_elated_modules) since there are no issues when only the first is removed and then added.

Comment: However, how can I find out what to do with regards wp_localize_script ?

& just to be clear: I don't want to enqueue my own script, just want to enqueue the same script as in the parent, but now from the child so I can modify it.

Comment: should i add the script with wp_localize_script ?

Comment: Could you post the part of the code from the parent theme with the wp_localize_script?

Comment: I have added the part with the wp_localize_script and modified the sample of functions.php in childtheme (which now dequeues / enqueues all script called in parent) and new screenshot (with only 2 instead of 4 errors now). Hope this is going somewhere...

Comment: This makes more sense now. What's happening is that in _listings.js_ there is an undefined variable `eltd` that is probably passed to original script with `wp_localize_script()`. Same goes for `eltdGlobalVars` in _modules.js_. What you need to do is find what those variables do in the parent theme and pass them into your child theme scripts with `wp_localize_script` as well. This should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My childtheme folder is an exact copy of the parent now, just to be sure. + I have enqueued the scripts (while adding child_ in front of their new handles) like you told me: with the same name as the pluggable functions. + I have copied the functions in parent were the scripts are called and renamed handle (adding child_ in front). This solved the "eltdGlobalVars ReferenceError" (yay!) but not the "eltd ReferenceError". I could not find where this eltd variable on line 4 is defined... I've added the first couple lines of code of the file listings.js above

Comment: @PimHeijden Would be great if you could add an answer below that starts to go over what solved this for you - I know it's not completely solved yet, but you can then edit as we get there. Comments are transient; an answer will stick around :) (and yes, you're allowed to self-answer)

Comment: Thanks for that tip TM. Can I expect more help solving the last bit? Can I do something to stimulate this or should I just be patient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enqueued the child script the right way and made the first Reference Error (eltdGlobalVars) disappear as follows:

In functions.php in child I removed lines that dequeue the script "search_and_go_elated_listing". Then I enqueued it using a copy of the function with the same name as the pluggable function in parent: "search_and_go_elated_listing_assets". Within this copy I modified the location of script to location in childtheme and I made sure to recognize the handle, adding "child_" to it.

It looks like this:

```
function search_and_go_elated_listing_assets() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'search_and_go_elated_listings', ELATED_ASSETS_ROOT.'/css/listings.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'child_search_and_go_elated_listings', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/listings.js', array('jquery', 'underscore', 'jquery-ui-autocomplete'), false, true );

    if(search_and_go_elated_is_responsive_on()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'search_and_go_elated_listings_responsive', ELATED_ASSETS_ROOT.'/css/listings-responsive.min.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'search_and_go_elated_listing_assets' );
```

Then I also copied the pieces of script were "search_and_go_elated_lising" is mentioned, changing it's handle to "child_search_and_go_elated_lising". In example below in combination with the variable GlobalVars, menioned in the original error:

```
function search_and_go_elated_get_global_variables() {

    $global_variables = array();
    $element_appear_amount = -150;

    $global_variables['eltdAddForAdminBar'] = is_admin_bar_showing() ? 32 : 0;
    $global_variables['eltdElementAppearAmount'] = search_and_go_elated_options()->getOptionValue('element_appear_amount') !== '' ? search_and_go_elated_options()->getOptionValue('element_appear_amount') : $element_appear_amount;
    $global_variables['eltdFinishedMessage'] = esc_html__('No more posts', 'search-and-go');
    $global_variables['eltdMessage'] = esc_html__('Loading new posts...', 'search-and-go');

    $global_variables = apply_filters('search_and_go_elated_js_global_variables', $global_variables);

    wp_localize_script('child_search_and_go_elated_modules', 'eltdGlobalVars', array(
        'vars' => $global_variables
    ));

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'search_and_go_elated_get_global_variables');
```

Second Reference Error (eltd) is solved by rightly prioritizing the actions adding the scripts. This is obvious now I understand it: Make sure that variables are defined before they are referenced!

Since I'm enqueueing several scripts in functions.php in child the other might have been changed with respect to the parent. So in order to solve the reference error in listings.js I made sure it was enqueued later than the other scripts (later than modules.js to be specific).